# Django features in a PHP Framework?

Tags: php, django, cakephp, symfony

There are two main features that I love in Django:
a) It creates the SQL table automatically from the Model
b) It auto generates a powerful admin from the Model

Is there a PHP framework with these two features? I've looked at Symfony and cakePHP, but I couldn't find any info about a)

Thanks!

Comment: Not really a good question for SO, but have a look at SilverStripe - http://www.silverstripe.org - similar ORM with migration handling, customisable backend cms.

Comment: Yii has powerful generators http://www.yiiframework.com/

Comment: not really a question

Answer (score 2):

I heard good things about [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), but in principle:

1. It works in reverse to Django, where its ORM dynamically match your Model's member variables to database tables.
2. It also has several scaffolding library [(example)](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) to generate simple CRUD admin page.

Answer (score 2):

1. Symfony uses ORM Doctrine that generates database tables based on entity mapping
2. There is no auto-generated admin dashboard in Symfony2, but there are bundles for that (e.g. SonataAdminBundle)